# Using ScreenshotKeywords from SeleniumLibrary

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I'm trying to create a custom python library that I can use with `RobotFramework` to run my tests. So far, I've only had issues with using the `capture_page_screenshot()` method from within my code. I can't seem to figure out the right way to call the function.

How do I get around this?

```
from SeleniumLibrary import ScreenshotKeywords

def screenshot():
    ScreenshotKeywords.capture_page_screenshot()
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is to get a reference to the selenium library that has been imported by your suite, and then call the keyword on that instance. You can get a reference to the library with the built-in keyword [get library instance](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Get%20Library%20Instance)

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

def screenshot():
    se2lib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance("SeleniumLibrary")
    se2lib.capture_page_screenshot()
```